# binding an array to a view model using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

is there a way to define an array and bind it to a view model? or does it have to be defined as an object?:

---- js ----

```
var arr = [{"id":"1","desc":"1","enabled":true,"tabStr":"/2 * * * * * *"},
            {"id":"2","desc":"2","enabled":true,"tabStr":"1-60/2 * * * * * *"},
            {"id":"3","desc":"3","enabled":false,"tabStr":"/5 * * * * * *"}];

$(document).ready(function(){
  ko.applyBindings(arr);
});
```

----- html ----

```
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: ???">
      <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: desc"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: tabStr"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: enabled"></td>
      </tr> 
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to wrap your array in an object, then you can use the special context variable `$data` (or `$root` since this is the top-level view model) to bind against the current data. So, your binding would look like:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: $data">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: desc"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: tabStr"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: enabled"></td>
  </tr> 
</tbody>
```

You can find more information about the context variables here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

Comment: Unless there is more to your data, `$root` and `$data` should be the same for you at that top-level.  Sounds like you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "arr", I use MVC, so I use `Model` (I left my version of what I would use as "arr"), and have a `@using IEnumerable<MyViewModel>` at the top of my view, and I have the controller doing something like:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
     var data = myDataContext.SomeTable.Where(e => e.blah == "Foo"); 
     return View(data);
}
```

And this returns something like your `arr`, so I think my code, below, should work fine for you:

```
<table border="1" width="100%" data-bind="foreach: mainArray">
    <tr>
        <td width="25%">ID</td>
        <td width="25%">Desc</td>
        <td width="25%">Enabled</td>
        <td width="25%">TabStr</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="25%" data-bind="text: id"></td>
        <td width="25%" data-bind="text: desc"></td>
        <td width="25%" data-bind="text: tabStr"></td>
        <td width="25%" data-bind="text: enabled"></td>
    </tr> 
</table>
<script language="type/Javascript">
    var arr = [{"id":"1","desc":"1","enabled":true,"tabStr":"2"},
        {"id":"2","desc":"2","enabled":true,"tabStr":"1-60"},
        {"id":"3","desc":"3","enabled":false,"tabStr":"5"}];
    //var arr = [@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))][0];

    $(function () {

         var myViewModel = new MyViewModel(arr);
         ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);

         function MyViewModel(arr) {
             var self = this;
             self.mainArray = ko.observableArray([]);

             if (arr.length > 0) {
                 for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                     var myDataViewModel = new MyDataViewModel(arr[i]);
                     self.mainArray.push(myDataViewModel);
                 } 
             }
         }

         function MyDataViewModel(vm) {
            //alert(vm.id);
            var self = this;
            if (vm != null) {                     
               self.id = ko.observable(vm.id);
               self.desc = ko.observable(vm.desc);
               self.enabled = ko.observable(vm.enabled);
               self.tabStr = ko.observable(vm.tabStr);
           } else {
              self.id = 0;
              self.desc = 0;
              self.enabled = true;
              self.tabStr = 0;
           }
        }
     });

</script>
```

Working JSFiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/navyjax2/y75hcr2L/